# Example for $f \in \mathcal{L}^q(\mathbb{R}, \lambda) \setminus \mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R}, \lambda)$ for $q < p$

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

We consider $q, p \in [1, \infty)$. I'm required to show that $\mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R}, \lambda) \subsetneq \mathcal{L}^q(\mathbb{R}, \lambda)$ and $\mathcal{L}^q(\mathbb{R}, \lambda) \subsetneq \mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R}, \lambda)$. Let's assume without loss of generality: $q < p$.

I was already able to show the second statement by defining:

$$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\hspace{15pt}x \mapsto \mathbb{1}_{[1, \infty)}(x) \cdot x^{-\frac{1}{q}}$$

We get $f \in \mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R}, \lambda)\,\setminus\, \mathcal{L}^q(\mathbb{R}, \lambda))$, but I fail to come up with $g \in \mathcal{L}^q(\mathbb{R}, \lambda) \,\setminus\, \mathcal{L}^p(\mathbb{R}, \lambda)$.

Comment: Your function is only in $L^p$ if $p > q$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Thank you. I forgot to add this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $x \mapsto 1_{(0,1)}(x) \cdot x^{-\frac 1p}$.

Comment: Coincidentally, my answer is surprisingly similar to yours. Perhaps this is a canonical example in some sense.

Comment: I think it is. It also complements the example of the OP to illustrate the roles of finite vs infinite measure sets.

Comment: Thank you! I do understand your example, but don't really seem to grasp the "roles of finite vs infinite measure sets".

Answer (score 1):

Let $r:=\frac{p+q}2$. Consider the function 
$$
f(x):=\mathbf 1_{[0,1]} x^{-1/r},
$$
we have
$$
\int_0^1 x^{-q/r} dx <\infty
$$
but 
$$
\int_0^1 x^{-p/r} dx =\infty.
$$

Comment: Thank you again!